# 2011-2013 Movie about a guy who can shapeshift an arm into a blade and is chased by an organisation of people like him

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I'm looking for a movie about a guy who can shapeshift his arm into a long greyish bone blade. He acquired this some time into the movie

I think he moved to a new town. He tries reporting weird occurrences he sees in the new town to the cops (if I'm not wrong). This leads him to being chased by a group of human like beings that can shapeshift both arms into blades.

The protagonist either acquired the same ability by being a hybrid of sorts or through some infection. (I don't know/remember)

The last few scenes is him fighting a woman that shapeshift both her arms into blades. It takes him a while to stab his own bone blade into her.

The movie was made roughly between 2000 and 2012, possibly later but before 2015.

The blades look something like this but the movie isn't *Mutant Chronicles*:

[image: Image of an arm blade piercing a helmet from Mutant Chronicles] [image: Fan art of Alex's arm blades in Prototype]

[image: Image of Alex from Prototype and his arm blade] [image: Front cover of Mutant Hunt with a mutant with a long arm blade]

The blades aren't metallic in the movie but they seemed to be constructed from hardened organic material. (When they shifted back into a normal hand they blew away like dust. The reverse when they appeared.)- not sure about this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Good first question! If you haven't already, please do take the [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: Extendable bone blades? Who would ever [believe such a thing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolverine)?

Comment: Note:   We don't change acceptable, but non-US, spellings to US spellings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This might be ***[The Deaths of Ian Stone](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0810823/)*** (2007).

[image]

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Deaths_of_Ian_Stone):

> *The Deaths of Ian Stone* is a 2007 British-American horror film directed by Dario Piana. The film stars Mike Vogel and Christina Cole.
>
> The story centers on an American man living in Britain, Ian Stone (Vogel), who is killed each day by mysterious beings. He then enters a new existence, unaware of his prior lives. When he begins to remember past existences, he is once again in danger of being killed, with each death more gruesome than the last.

From the [Shapeshifter Weapon](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShapeshifterWeapon) page on TV Tropes:

> The Harvesters in *The Deaths of Ian Stone* use a [Blade Below the Shoulder](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BladeBelowTheShoulder) version of this with both arms. Antagonists go full-on One-Winged Angel, but our hero shifts noticeably less than them, and eventually gains the ability to take advantage of this trope while remaining otherwise normal.

The video clip below shows the main antagonist with her right arm morphed into a dark, somewhat bony-looking blade.

This clip shows the protagonist morphing his own right arm into a similar blade.

Comment: Yep that's it. Thank you very much. It was killing me

Comment: Video "blocked in your country" (U.S.), fyi.

Comment: @John C - Thanks for the heads up. I've now replaced both clips with ones that aren't blocked in the US. Unfortunately, the second clip doesn't include the original audio, but the relevant visuals are there.